# how to manually set auto-generated id from lombok with mySQL workbench?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, lombok, jpa

I have an app with a few entities annotated with lombok's `@Data`, and using

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
```

for the id. It's generally working fine. But I needed to manually insert a row via mySQL Workbench, with id=635. This screwed up the app, when it tried to insert it's next row, because what it thought or calculated would be the next id, 635, already existed. I thought I could manually increment the id, but I couldn't find it anywhere via mySQL workbench.

So where does lombok/hibernate/jpa calculate or generate the next id? And is there a way to manually change it in the db, or at least with another SQL?

I'm not sure which framework does this, since it's using `javax.persistence` for the annotations, but also `lombok.Data`, and then in the app.properties, there is no dialect set, but I have a `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl` key, so I'm not sure if that pulls in bits of hibernate as well.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Lombok and is entirely your persistence provider, probably using a database sequence. Note that it's not generally a good idea to use `@Data` on entities, since the defining characteristic of entities is that they have an identity that is distinct from their values; use `@Getter @Setter` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I needed to do more googling before posting. Found this answer [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/auto_increment_reset.php):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 636;
```